# How to know when a list is long enough to be scrollable?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The screenshot below consists of two product listings, one which is too short to be scrollable, the other which is long enough to be scrollable.

[image]

Below is the screenshot with more visible colours for better clarity for the sake of this question:

[image]

To indicate to the user that the list is scrollable, I have stacked the list with a gradient which is at the end of the list.

I would like this gradient to only appear when the list is long enough to be scrollable, but I am not able to find a way to differentiate between the scrollable and non-scrollable lists.

Below is the code for the stack which has the underlying list and the gradient:

```dart
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: <Widget>[
        //children go here
      ],
    ),
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
      child: Container(
        width: 24,
        height: 24,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: FractionalOffset.centerRight,
            end: FractionalOffset.centerLeft,
            colors: [
              Colors.green,
              Colors.yellow
            ],
            stops: [
              0.0,
              1.0
            ]))),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that your question is more assertive. The way it is, it's too abstract.

Comment: Basically you're asking how to tell if the height of the scrollable's contents is greater than the height off the scrollable? Are you using a builder?

Comment: @BrenoTeodoro Sure

Comment: @DaveNewton I have added more details to the question summary, I hope that will provide some clarity.

Answer (score 1):

I made a simple case for your request.
At first build list and calculate all item's widht sum,
and if all item's width is over Listview container's width,
 redraw show indicator that it can be scrollable.

## modified

I changed to get a width dynamic ListView width.
You can just test with chaning 'listItemLength' value.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "App",
      theme: new ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.amber),
      home: Test(),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  List<GlobalKey> _globalKeys = [];
  GlobalKey _listviewGLobalKey = GlobalKey();
  double listTotalWidth = 0.0;
  double listviewWidth = 0.0;
  int listItemLength = 14;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    for (var i = 0; i < listItemLength; i++) {
      _globalKeys.add(GlobalKey());
    }

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _getSizes());
  }

  _getSizes() {
    // Get a total Items width
    listTotalWidth = 0.0;
    _globalKeys.forEach((key) {
      final RenderBox renderBoxRed = key.currentContext.findRenderObject();
      final containerSize = renderBoxRed.size;
      listTotalWidth += containerSize.width;
    });
    print('total items width sum: $listTotalWidth');

    // Get a ListView's width
    final RenderBox listviewRenderBoxRed =
        _listviewGLobalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    final listviewContainerSize = listviewRenderBoxRed.size;
    listviewWidth = listviewContainerSize.width;
    print('ListView width: $listviewWidth');

    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // print('**** ${_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent}');
    //  WidgetsBinding.instance
    //           .addPostFrameCallback((_) => _getSizes());
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "Title",
      theme: new ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.amber),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    key: _listviewGLobalKey,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    itemCount: listItemLength,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Container(
                          key: _globalKeys[index],
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                          child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                            'aaa$index',
                          )));
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                if (listTotalWidth > listviewWidth) Icon(Icons.add),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but in my case, my list view is not having a fixed width, since the device width is variable width, I have kept the middle column of listing as expandable.

Comment: @UditChugh You can do it like this.
You can get a width ListView's dynamic width value.
My example just fixed ListView's width, but with GlobalKey and rederBoxSize also can get a width.

Comment: I modified for your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

attach a `ScrollController` to the `ListView` 
and then use it (in a hack way) to determine scrollability of the list

```
    ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();


    return Container(
      height: 24,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 24),
            child: ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              controller: _scrollController,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('aaaindex'),
                Text('aaaindex'),
                Text('aaaindex'),
                Text('aaaindex'),
                Text('aaaindex'),
                Text('aaaindex'),
                Text('aaaindex'),
                Text('aaaindex'),
                Text('aaaindex'),
                Text('aaaindex'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          FutureBuilder(
            future: Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500))
            builder: (context,async){
              if(async.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                return Container();
              }
              return _scrollController.position.extentAfter > 0
                  ? Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child: Container(
                  width: 24,
                  height: 24,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                      begin: FractionalOffset.centerRight,
                      end: FractionalOffset.centerLeft,
                      colors: [Colors.green, Colors.yellow],
                      stops: [0.0, 1.0],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
                  : Container();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: When I test with your code, there is a exception.
`flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<dynamic>(dirty, state:
flutter: _FutureBuilderState<dynamic>#3793d):
flutter: The method '-' was called on null`

Comment: it is the `function` in the future delay; change `future`  to `future: Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500), (){})`

Comment: @MuhammadAdam Thanks, this is working, but I also am getting the exception @KuKu mentioned, and can you elaborate a bit on what is happening here and why are we using the `FutureBuilder`?

Comment: I think that FutureBuilder is for waiting ListView is built. So scrollable indicator is shown later than ListView.

Comment: during the build process, the scrollController is not attached to the ListView yet; so we simply wait 500 milliseconds before dealing with the scrollController until they are attached; you can give it a try and remove the `FutureBuilder` and see what's happens

Comment: @MuhammadAdam Got it, even with the `FutureBuilder` I get this exception: The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<Null>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<Null>#02977):
The method '-' was called on null.

Comment: use the updated code: the change is : ````builder: (context,async){
              if(async.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
                return Container();
              }````

Comment: also, you can use `extentBefore` and `extentAfter` to align the `Align` widget left or right depending on the scroll status; at the beginning, `extentBefore` is zero and it increases upon scroll; `extentAfter` is the opposite;

Comment: @MuhammadAdam Wow I had a good idea from your code!!! Thank you very much. I suggest you to use 'FutureBuilder' rather than 'addPostFrameCallback'.

Comment: @MuhammadAdam Thanks! The updated code made the exception go away, I will keep the question open since this is a workaround and we might have someone give us a non-hackish way.

Answer (score 1):

This idea is from 'Muhammad Adam'.
When judge whether listview is scrollable, I used 'extentAfter' rather than 'renderBox size'.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  bool _scrollable = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _getIsScrollable());
  }

  _getIsScrollable() {
    print(_scrollController.position.extentAfter > 0);
    _scrollable = _scrollController.position.extentAfter > 0;
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: _buildBody(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody() {
    return Container(
      height: 24,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 24),
            child: ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              controller: _scrollController,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('aaaindex'),
                Text('aaaindex'),
                Text('aaaindex'),
                Text('aaaindex'),
                Text('aaaindex'),
                Text('aaaindex'),
                Text('aaaindex'),
                Text('aaaindex'),
                Text('aaaindex'),
                Text('aaaindex'),
                Text('aaaindex'),
                Text('aaaindex'),
                Text('aaaindex'),
                Text('aaaindex'),
                Text('aaaindex'),
                Text('aaaindex'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          if (_scrollable)
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child: Container(
                width: 24,
                height: 24,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: FractionalOffset.centerRight,
                    end: FractionalOffset.centerLeft,
                    colors: [Colors.green, Colors.yellow],
                    stops: [0.0, 1.0],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```